# How to make a radio button in BrewMp?

Tags: brewmp

How to make a radio button in Brew MP. Please anyone can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [UI Widgets documentation in BrewMP API Reference](https://developer.brewmp.com/reference/api/brew_mp_1.0.2/ui/widgets).